# R Web Scraping rvest forms submit_form

Tags: forms, rvest

I am new to r and not very knowledgeable about html, xml etc. I am trying to scrape a site that requires input from a drop down. It's for an academic paper using text and sentiment analysis on the press releases of members of congress. NOT A PROGRAMMER LOL So be gentle!

```
memberUrl = 'https://grijalva.house.gov/press-releases/'
session <- html_session(memberUrl)
forms <- html_form(session)
yearForm <- forms[[4]]
#--- so far so good (I think) -- and i have successfully scraped sites that don't have drop downs
#--- but here is where I get confused and can't find a good tutorial on forms and submit_form
set_values(yearForm, ??? ) #----- get stuck on how to use set_values
submit_form( session, yearForm, ???) #--- and here
```

Thanks! Jim

Answer (score 1):

`submit_form` didn't work, maybe because that form uses JS to submit. Here is the solution:

```
library(rvest)
memberUrl = 'https://grijalva.house.gov/press-releases/'
session <- html_session(memberUrl)

session <- rvest:::request_POST(session,
                                memberUrl,
                                body = list(
                                  getNewsByyear = "2018" #change the value here, 'getNewsByyear' is the name of the dropdown list
                                ))

titles <- read_html(session) %>%
  html_nodes("ul > li > h3") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! This worked! I really appreciate your taking the time to read my post and answer! Best to you!

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work any longer, as `rvest:::request_POST()` appears to have gone away...

Comment: @MattCowgill Yes. This only works with rvest before 1.0